# defining a constant to be used in different namespace php 5.4

Tags: php, namespaces, constants

i have a problem accessing a constant that is defined in another namespace

this is the class that has the constant defined in

```
<?php namespace App\Box

class Green
{
  const COLOR = 'green';
}
```

this is the class that is used to instantiate an instance from the first class

```
<?php namespace App\Tests

use App\Box\Green

class Test1
{
   protected $box;

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->box = new Green;
   }
}
```

i get the following error

```
Use of undefined constant COLOR - assumed 'COLOR'
```

Comment: ; after namespace / use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because wherever you've used `/`, you need to use `\`. This works for me:

```
namespace App\Box {
    class Green {
        const COLOR = 'green';
    }
}

namespace App\Tests {

    use App\Box\Green;

    class Test1 {
        public function __construct() {
            echo Green::COLOR;
        }
    }

    $t = new Test1(); // green
}
```

What are you looking to do?

Comment: oh, actually i'm using "\" , i typed it by mistake "/"

Comment: okay it is working, i used the double colon as in your example, thanks

Comment: Ah right. Yes; you access constants as if they're static properties - you could also use `self::COLOR` to access the constant within the `Green` class.